# Memory Dump - Windows CE

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, windbg, memory-dump

I am having an issue at a client site with a .NET/Windows CE 5.0 application.  Of course, we are not able to duplicate the issue and the client doesn't know exactly how to duplicate it either.  I've had some experience using SOS/WinDbg to debug .NET issues on the full .NET Framework.  I was wondering if there is a way to take a memory dump of a WinCE 5.0 process so I can attempt to debug with WinDbg.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [WinCE Test Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22906) Application Verifier.

Comment: I wasn't able to get that app to connect to my device :(